# Is there a way to prevent spamming votes?

Tags: discussion, voting, up-votes, serial-voting

While I was working on an app, I was reading on question on SO. After a while (half an hour) i returned to the same question.I refreshed the page, and saw that the questioner had a considerable increase in reputation changed  ( 160 rep ), in HALF AN HOUR. Now, I know it is possible for people to upvote a lot a user that has been successful, but (here comes the question) is there a way to prevent a specific user to spam his upvotes in a given amount of time, and specifically to e given user? F.e.:

Once upon a time there was a user that found an answer to a difficult
problem he was having. Oh,happy day! He felt so happy that he decided
to  upvote every f**** post of the lucky user who helped him! But of
course he would do that in a hurry because he still had plenty of work
to do...

Is it any good to detect if a given user is giving away too much votes to a specific user in a given amount of time (small amount of time)? I think that these situatuions may happen and are not any good to the purpose of SO.

Comment: Please don't abuse code formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are already automated tools in place to detect this kind of behaviour (serial voting) and reverse it. I believe they run once a day so this should, if applicable, be corrected within about 24 hours.

Answer (score 3):

What you're referring to is serial voting. There is a process that runs nightly that rescinds votes where one user voted too often for another user's posts.